# Default contex menu for Shortcuts

Tags: windows-xp

I installed the FilesMenu software, and there was some issue while opening shortcuts to application on the desktop. So I un-installed the software and Restart system.

Still the same problem is there. When I right click there is no "Open " option in contex menu also when I hit enter application fail to launch.

Its working fine with exe files.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced a similar problem when installing an old version of PowerDesk on my Windows 7 laptop; the context menus didn't open at all and Explorer just crashed.

I discovered a utility by NirSoft called [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) which enables you to disable / enable various context menu items.

You could then use a simple divide and conquer system, i.e. disable half the context menu items you think may be the problem, reboot and see if problem continues; if not check the other half. You can then whittle the problem down to the menu item which is causing the problem and leave it disabled.